# Heroku ErrorPlanNotFound

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, fork, heroku-toolbelt, heroku-cli

I'm trying to change my Heroku app region by following this official guide:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/app-migration.

The problem is that, when I try to fork it at the very beginning using:

`heroku fork --from keepmefit --to keepmefit-eu --region eu`.

Heroku cli returns:

```
Forking keepmefit... done. Forked to keepmefit-eu
Setting buildpacks... done
Creating heroku-postgresql:dev on keepmefit-eu... !
 !    ErrorPlanNotFound

There was an error forking to keepmefit-eu.

In order to avoid being charged for any resources on keepmefit-eu, it is being destroyed...
Destroying app keepmefit-eu... done
```

I'm using the latest version of Heroku Cli 6.15.18-fdf2097 in Windows 10

Answer (score 1):

> Heroku ErrorPlanNotFound

That means Heroku showing Error:

> Plan Not Found

Plan missing on the targeted app which already has the previous app.

It is not allowed on the free/unverified Heroku account [here the documentation](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-fork) said

> The forking user will be the owner of the app and responsible for any
>   application charges. For this reason, your account needs to be
>   verified if the application you're forking contains paid resources.

If your old app have any add- h plan then same plan need to have on target/new app

That's why you seeing the below message from CLI

> In order to avoid being charged for any resources on keepmefit-eu, it
>   is being destroyed...

Hope it helps